# Why isn't my Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu working?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Recently, I have started web developing and I am using bootstrap v5.0 to build a website. Following is the code of a file named "grage.php", and its code is stated below,

```
<!-- HERE SHOULD BE THE CODE OF GARAGE    -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- CODE FOR OPTIONS-->
        <div class="col-3" style="align-items: center;">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown button
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- CODE FOR DISPLAYING MODEL -->
        <div class="col-7">
            <div style="align-items: center;">
                <model-viewer src="car_models/compressed_civic.glb" alt="A 3D model of an astronaut" ar ar-modes="webxr scene-viewer quick-look" environment-image="neutral" auto-rotate camera-controls>
                </model-viewer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- CODE FOR DISPLAYING CHOOSED OPTION'S AND ETC-->
        <div class="col-2">
            <p>Here should be the code for option's</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ADDING FOOTER   -->
<?php
include "headerAndFooter/footer.php";
?>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer-legacy.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I am having problem as the dropdown function is not working as shown below, [Dropdown Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCgNT.png)

Note: I have added the bootstrap css CDN link in the header.

Please let me know, how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> I am using bootstrap v5.0

But you've loaded bootstrap 4. That's why it's not working. Bootstrap 4 uses `data-toggle="dropdown"` and bootstrap 5 uses `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"`. You need to load the right JavaScript/CSS for it to work.

Bootstrap 4 Example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
        </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Bootstrap 5 Example:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
        </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you're using the Bootstrap 5 CDN that includes Popper:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

From the bootstrap 5 installation guide: https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 1):

Also is important don´t include more than one script like

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Because not working. Only needs ones like says Nick

Answer (score 0):

Here only Change the attribute
data-toggle='dropdown' (Bootstrap 4.6) to data-bs-toggle='dropdown' (Bootstrap 5.2).

Then dropdown menu in bootstarp 5.2 is working fine.